# Elasticbeanstalk overrides nginx.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to increase the `client_max_body_size` in nginx and it works if I ssh into the server and restart, but the changes are gone after the next `eb deploy`.

How would I achieve persistence across deployments?

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, because the site is live and there's a conference. I will do it on Monday and report back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumint that you are using EB platform based on `Amazon Linux 2`, you have to create `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` file in your application with the content of, for example:

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```